# Sonar : How get Code Coverage in dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan

Code coverage is showing as zero when am running sonar-runner for Maven and TS. In sonar dashboard, Bugs, vulnerabilities, Duplications, and code smells are showing perfectly fine but not code coverage showing as 0.0%
Please guide me what are all steps need to get code coverage in sonar dashboard for each project.

Comment: when you run maven site, is coverage repport created in /target/site ? How do you set coverage for your project ? in pom.xml ? in command line ?